# Make button active (md-button)

Tags: angular, material-design

I am wont to implement select menu from list.
I have some md-card of dishes, and when the user click on some of them, the button stay active, until user click again.

something like this:

```
 <div fxFlex *ngFor="let dish of category.dishes">
     <button md-raised-button (click)="dish.isSelected = !dish.isSelected"  [active]="dish.isSelected">
                            <md-card> 
                             .....
```

any idea how to do this?